# Jenkins: deploy to firebase. Your refresh token has been revoked

Tags: jenkins, authentication, firebase, continuous-integration, firebase-tools

I have a firebase solution hosted. I'm using Jenkins to build, run test and deploy every time there is a commit done in git.

So the last shell command jenkins runs is giving me the issue:

```
firebase deploy --non-interactive --token "MY TOKEN GOES HERE"
```

I got this token from running on my console the command

```
firebase login:ci
```

which opens a browser and after confirmation it will give you a token.

But this works when I run the command locally but when I run this on jenkins, I get:

```
Error: Your refresh token has been revoked, please login to obtain a
new one.
```

My guess is I need to run

```
firebase login:ci
```

from the same console that runs the deploy commmand, but how do I do that in Jenkins?

Any other guesses?

Comment: Hi Frank,  I am using below firebase cli command to upload iOS app to firebase through Jenkins but it is saying firebase command not found. But if I am using the same command through Mac terminal, it's working successfully. So can you please let me know do I need to install any Jenkins plugin to make firebase command work for Jenkins. Your help would be appreciated.  firebase appdistribution:distribute test.ipa  \
    --app 1:1234567890:ios:0a1b2c3d4e5f67890  \
    --release-notes "Bug fixes and improvements" --testers-file testers.txt

Comment: Hi AAlferezm, can you please let me know how you configure firebase for jenkins, because when i am trying to run firebase command over jenkins execute shell, it showing error - firebase command not found.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did, installed nodejs plugin on jenkins. Then in the Jenkins settings  Configure tools -> NodeJs installation -> "Global npm packages to install" I just added to firebase-tools ..

In my local windows machine, I added nodejs and then installed firebase-tools and ran firebase login:ci, this provided me a token once I logged into firebase using my credentials.

In Jenkins, from pipeline script after the build, I just did the following, firebase deploy --token '******'. That's it. I was able to deploy it.

Answer (score 0):

```sh
firebase login --no-localhost
```

will generate a link to be opened manually in any browser and generate token.

You can copy the generated token from browser and paste it in your cli.

Answer (score -2):

I have passed the same problem. Also, we did this to run firebase with Jenkins.

First, we tried the same command as you.

```
firebase login:ci
```

I copied the URL that Firebase provided, and after I had inputted my credentials, I was redirected to localhost.

So, I tried the following command:

```
firebase login --interactive
```

Again, I have copied the URL, pasted in a browser, but there aren't a way to paste the generated token. It always shows the following message:

```
Waiting for authentication...
```

So, I have tried the following command:

```
firebase login --no-localhost
```

Then, it showed the prompt for the token:

```
? Paste authorization code here: 4/UnzYx4O3aB...
```

So finally, it could log in.

I hope this can help someone.